# How to calculate the generalized inverse of a matrix on new columns

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, generalized-inverse

Assume that there exists a matrix $A∈R^{m×n}(m≠n)$ whose generalized inverse matrix is $X$, and $X$ satifies the formula:
$$
A=AXA\\
(XA)^T=XA
$$
How to calculate the generalized inverse matrix Y of $B=[A,a](a∈R^{m×t},m\neq t)$,which also satifies the formula(the matrix $A$, the matrix $a$, the generalized inverse matrix of $A$ have been known):
$$
B=BYB\\
(YB)^T=YB
$$

Comment: Maybe you can check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix_pseudoinverse